# Слово "похабный"

Tags: этимология

Интересно было бы узнать этимологию слова "похабный". Почему это означает "пошлый"?
Спасибо

Comment: Это не означает "пошлый", скорее грубый, бесстыдный, неприличный, (с сексуальным оттенком). "Пошлость" же - скорее примитив, отсутствие вкуса.

> низкопробный в духовном, нравственном отношении, чуждый высоких интересов и запросов; заурядный 
> безвкусно-грубый, избитый, банальный 
> вульгарный, содержащий что-либо неприличное, непристойное  

Подходит только последнее значение, но в "пошлости" оно менее резко выраженное.

Answer (score 1):

Это слово, заимствованное из старославянского, образовано суффиксальным способом от существительного похабъ – "дурень, юродивый", восходящего к той же основе, что и диалектальное хабалка – "нахалка"

Comment: Если так, непонятно, почему в слове "похабный" появился оттенок не просто дурости, а неприличия? При этом слове так и представляется сальная ухмылка и грубый гогот.

Comment: Там есть значение не просто дурной, а испорченный, никудышный. Думаю, это объясняет.

Answer (score 0):

Вот что написано в Вики:

> Происходит от "похаб" - др.-рус. "святой", "богоугодный".

Конечно, википедия - не авторитет, но все же! Странное сближение.

Comment: Да нет, это-то как раз было бы нормально, если бы было достоверно. Вспомните, как к юродивым на Руси относились. "Юродивый - человек Божий". Но сомнительно, ибо у Фасмера другое:
  
>поха́бить поха́бный, диал. также "горячий (о лошадях)", олонецк. (Кулик.). От русск.-цслав. хабити " портить", хабень " жалкий" (см. ха́бить), укр. оха́бити "погубить, испортить", болг. хабя́ "порчу" и т. д. (Бернекер 1, 380).  
  
  
А вообще Вики, конечно, тот еще источник.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас существует словарь старославянских слов:
[http://www.orthodic.org/?searchCs=&searchRu=похаб&go.x=0&go.y=0&type=ru](http://www.orthodic.org/?searchCs=&searchRu=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B1&go.x=0&go.y=0&type=ru)
Слово "похабный" очевидно происходит от глагола "похабити" - оскорблять, обижать.
В отношении "какой?" это очевидно имеет оттенок "глупый, жестокий, бесстыдный"(старое: "похаб")